# haskell front letters

Tags: haskell

So im educating myself for the future

```
firstLetter :: IO String
firstLetter = do
    x <- getChar
    if (x == ' ')
        then return (show x)
        else firstLetter
```

So it would get lines until the first line, that starts with empty char
how can I do it, so if empty line comes, it returns all `head(x)`
for example:

```
Liquid
Osone
Liquid
(empty line)
returns
"LOL"
```

Comment: Hint: a space character is not a newline character.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.  The library function `lines` will split the input into lines for you, so all that is left is extracting the first character from each string in a list until one string is empty.  An empty string is just a null list, so you can check for that to end the recursion over the list of strings.

```
firstLetters :: [String] -> String
firstLetters (x:xs)
    | null x = []
    | otherwise = head x : firstLetters xs

main = do
    contents <- getContents
    putStrLn . firstLetters . lines $ contents
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen [`interact`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3ainteract)?  This'll help you eliminate the IO and that always seems to make thing simpler for me and hopefully you too.

That reduces it to a problem that reads a string and returns a string.

Here's a rough go at it.  `getLines` takes a string, breaks it into `lines` and consumes them (`takeWhile`) until it meets a line containing a single space (I wasn't sure on your ending condition, as the other poster says using `null` will stop at the first empty list).  Then it goes over those lines and gets the first character of each (with `map head`).

```
getLines :: String -> String
getLines = map head . takeWhile (/= " ") . lines

main :: IO ()
main = interact getLines
```

Comment: How can i create a list, where I will add every line first letter?

Comment: I've switched it over to a point-free style since it looks sexier. @SummerBreak, the code does add every first line letter.  `map head` goes over all the items in the list, selects the first character and returns the result

Comment: But how can i return ALL the letter AFTER i've inserted a line, that starts with ' '?

Comment: It'd be similar.  I guess you would use `dropWhile` instead of `takeWhile`.  That would ignore elements until it hit the first line that was ' '